# Derivative of $F^{-1}(x)$ where $F(x)=\int_{0 }^x\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt $

Tags: calculus, derivatives, inverse-function

Find $(F^{-1})'(x) $ in terms of $F^{-1}(x)$ where $$F(x)=\int_{0 }^x\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt $$

I  know that
$$(F^{-1})'(x) = \dfrac{1}{F'(F^{-1}(x))}$$

I calculated using Fundamental Theorem of Calculus,
$$F'(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} $$
But I don't know how to proceed

Comment: What does the fundamental theorem of calculus tell you abou $F’$ here?

Comment: I have calculated it

Comment: Now plug $F^{-1}$ instead of x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$F(x)=\int_{0 }^x\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt $$
By $t=\sin \theta$, 
$$
F(x) = \int_0^{\sin^{-1}(x)} \frac{\cos \theta d\theta}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta}} = \int_0^{\sin^{-1}(x)} d\theta  = \sin^{-1}(x)
$$
Because 
$$(F^{-1})'(x) = \dfrac{1}{F'(F^{-1}(x))} \quad \text{and} \quad F'(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$
So,

$$
(F^{-1})'(x) = \sqrt{1-\sin^2 x}
$$

Comment: How is the upper limit $\theta$ ?

Comment: You're right. My bad. Let me fix

Answer (score 2):

Since $F'(x)=\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$,$$(F^{-1})'(x)=\frac1{F'\bigl(F^{-1}(x)\bigr)}=\sqrt{1-\bigl(F^{-1}(x)\bigr)^2}.$$